# WAMP server 404

Tags: php, localhost, wamp

So yesterday i installed WAMP server and if I run it, the icon is green saying all of the services are running. I changed the port to the `8080` because `80` was used by some Windows process.

```
localhost:8080
```

gets me to the WAMP homepage, but if I click any of my projects (they appear in the homepage), I get `404 not found error`.

I tried

```
localhost:8080/test/index.php
```

I'm pretty sure the solution for this is easy but I can't wrap my head around it, thank you.

Comment: make sure you project is in the same directory as the WAMP homepage. something like wamp-directory/yourproject/index.php

Comment: Its in "C:\wamp64\www\test\index.php" The funny thing is that my test folder appears on the homepage of wamp, meaning that it finds it

Comment: Try to enable **mod_rewrite** module in **Apache** of your newly installed WAMP if not already enabled.

Comment: Wamp -> Apache -> Apache modules ->  rewrite_module was enabled before, tried this when trying to find a solution, sadly it was already enabled by the default, but still thank you

Comment: If above solution will not resolved your issue, then try to change **ServerName localhost:80** to **ServerName localhost:8080** in your httpd.conf file (I hope this one also you already been done)

Comment: try to check if theres a .htaccess file on the project folder.. sometimes.. it messes up the routes...

Comment: It would be easier to find out what is using port 80 `left click wampmanager -> Apache -> Test Port 80` Report back in your question what is reported on the screen

Comment: `Your port 80 is actually used by :

Server: Apache/2.4.17 (Win64) PHP/5.6.16`

Comment: I can access the Wampserver homepage by typing `localhost` , but when I click on my folder for the project (which contains index.php file in explorer) I get error: `Not Found
    The requested URL /test/ was not found on this server.`

Comment: Please try here, http://www.steptoinstall.com/page-not-found-404-error-in-wamp-server-localhost.html

Answer (score 0):

try this url to check the wamp work properly or not.

```
 localhost:8080/phpmyadmin
```

if it not work change the port after try it.and then

localhost:8080/test/index.php

Comment: "The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration."

Comment: `Not Found

The requested URL /test/index.php was not found on this server.` for the index.php

Comment: confirm your index.php file in htdocs/test/index.php

Answer (score 0):

If you have Skype installed and running, go on advanced settings and disable port 80.

Restart Skype and WAMP then retry with port 80

Comment: I saw this solution before also, this is not a case, I don't use Skype.